# /\A[^@\s]+@([^@\s]+\.)+[^@\s]+\z/ Meaning?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

Can somebody please explain the meaning of

```
validates_format_of: :email, with: /\A[^@\s]+@([^@\s]+\.)+[^@\s]+\z/
```

I understand that is an email validation, but what is the break down of it?
How can I check if the format of a Youtube video is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Nice tool that explains parts of regex: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple regex:

Example Email: some@email.com

`\A`

Asserts position at the beginning of the string

`\A[^@\s]+`

Matches between 1 and unlimited characters without white spaces. (\s)

This would match here: "some"

`@`

Just matches the @.

`([^@\s]+\.)+`

Matches between 1 and unlimited characters without an @ or a whitespace, but with 1 or more "."

Here: "email."

`[^@\s]+`

Matches between 1 and unlimited characters without an @ or whitespace

Here: "com"

`\z`

Asserts position at the end of the string

You can validate YouTube video Urls with this regex:

`^(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)\/.+$`